# Where is log output written to when using Robolectric + Roboguice?

Tags: java, android, maven-2, roboguice, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric to test Android.  I'm running my tests via maven, e.g.

```
mvn -Dtest=LogTest test
```

If I have code that writes to the logs, such as

```
Log.d("TAG", "blah");
```

or using Roboguice's `Ln`

```
Ln.d("blah");
```

I don't see any output in maven's surefire logs (text files).

Ideally, I actually want simple log statements to go to the console.  I can write to the console by using `System.out.println("blah")`, but of course I'd rather use the supported logging APIs.

So my question is, why am I not seeing log output at all, and how can I get the log messages written to the console?

Comment: Does it work with info / error?

Comment: This is an old question, but I do want to ask Tyler to accept an answer. When you accept answers to your questions, people are more willing to answer your questions.

Comment: @Christine I agree Christine. However, I no longer have the ability to check if answers posted here work. At the time, none of the answers helped me. I upvoted scompt.com's answer, but then realized it didn't solve the issue for me, as I noted in the comments. Is there a policy/guide for what I should all this time later?

Comment: Jesus Monzon Legido's solution works fine, I use that. Also, it's the simplest solution given.

Answer (score 79):

I am running **robolectric-2.0-alpha-3**.

What worked for me was to set in the setUp method of my **test** the stream to `stdout`

Something like:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
  //you other setup here
}
```

With this version of robolectric I had no success doing the same (`ShadowLog.stream = System.out`) in a custom TestRunner or in my TestLifeycleApplication.

Setting the system property `System.setProperty("robolectric.logging","stdout");` was of no effect as well, but it might works in previous versions.

Comment: Great! I call this in a static method annotated with `@BeforeClass` to run this only once per test file.

Comment: Works on robolectric 3.0 as well.

Comment: Works on roboletric 4.5.1

Answer (score 15):

Im using robolectric 2.3. How works for me:

Into my @Before:

```
ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
```

Inside my test functions i can use (ShadowLog. have other options):

```
ShadowLog.v("tag", "message");
```

And inside my tested class I can put some messages at log with:

```
System.out.println("message");
```

Comment: I've tried it, but I see nothing. Where is the output written? Btw.: I use Robolectric 2.4, but I think logging will work in the same way.

Comment: U can see the result in the logcat. Verify if u put the ShadowLog.stream = System.out; into ur setup.

Comment: Why not just use `System.out`?  Why the necessity for `ShadowLog`.

Answer (score 13):

By default, logging output when using the [RobolectricTestRunner](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.java) disappears. You can configure where it goes by looking at the [setupLogging()](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.java#L695) method of that class.

To summarize, you need to set the `robolectric.logging` system property to either `stdout`, `stderr`, or a file path where the log should be written. I do this in the constructor of a subclass of `RobolectricTestRunner` that I use for all tests so that logs always get written to stdout.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks!  Good links too.  Now... did you read about that somewhere, or did you just dig through the source?  Also, are you familiar with Roboguice?  I was wanting to use their "Ln" logging, but if I do, it doesn't get printed out to stdout, although it's strange because it seems like its default implementation is via `android.util.Log`, which should work because I can use Log directly.  Thoughts?

Comment: I only found it by slogging through the code. I don't think it's documented anywhere. As for `Ln`, make sure your app is `debuggable`, otherwise `Ln` [automatically disables debug and verbose logging](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/Logging).

Comment: Rats.  Sorry to be dense.  I realize this did not actually solve my problem.  The code you pointed out makes sense, but it doesn't actually work.  I thought it was working, but it was leftover code I had used to make it work, from: http://groups.google.com/group/robolectric/browse_thread/thread/f1a5df8b3849a4f3?pli=1

Comment: Does setupLogging() still exist?  http://pivotal.github.io/robolectric/javadoc/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.html

Comment: Yes, it's still in [RobolectricTestRunner](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.java#L695), but the package has been changed.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to your test setup before your test runs:

```
ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowLog.class);
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/robolectric/PK-9cQQQROw/svuQzM5h_vsJ

Comment: I just test this with robolectric 2.x+.

`Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowLog.class);` is not longer needed.

Comment: Yup. This works.  As @Macarse says, the second line isn't needed - robolectric 2.2.

Comment: I get an error **Cannot resolve method 'bindShadowClass'

Answer (score 2):

When running tests with maven all you need is something like this :

```
                 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                          <robolectric.logging>stdout</robolectric.logging>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                 </plugin>
```

When running the tests locally, e.g. in intellij, then all you need is an environmental variable:
Just go (for intellij) to Run/Debug Configurations --> Defaults -->Junit --> VM options and add

```
-Drobolectric.logging=stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked out best for me (or at all) was to initialize a replacement injected implementation (during testing only) of RoboGuice's Ln.Print class to do System.out printing instead of Android's Log printing, given I was actually using Robolectric to avoid having to depend on the Android subsystem to run my tests in the first place.

From [Ln.java](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/util/Ln.java?r=a4ed698b0c851772e7c148deccced53c24c6ec40#68):

```
public class Ln  {
...

/**
 * print is initially set to Print(), then replaced by guice during
 * static injection pass.  This allows overriding where the log message is delivered to.
 */
@Inject protected static Print print = new Print();
```

So basically:

```
public class TestModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Ln.Print.class).to(TestLogPrint.class);
    }

}
```

and:

```
public class TestLogPrint extends Print {

    public int println(int priority, String msg ) {

        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "%s%s", 
                getScope(4), 
                msg
            )
        );

        return 0;
    }

    protected static String getScope(int skipDepth) {
        final StackTraceElement trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[skipDepth];
        return String.format("%s | %s.%s | ", new Date(), trace.getFileName().replace(".java", ""), trace.getMethodName());
    }
}
```

That of course assuming the standard Robolectric init to hook the module up with RoboGuice:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    Module roboGuiceModule = RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(Robolectric.application);
    Module productionModule = Modules.override(roboGuiceModule).with(new CustomRoboModule());
    Module testModule = Modules.override(productionModule).with(new TestModule());

    RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(Robolectric.application, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, testModule);
    RoboGuice.injectMembers(Robolectric.application, this);

}
```