# Robolectric 2.4 and android.util.Log

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, logging, robolectric, gradlew

How can I show the Log.d() output made in the application code when testing with Robolectric? Currently I use version 2.4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is log output written to when using Robolectric + Roboguice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219915/where-is-log-output-written-to-when-using-robolectric-roboguice)

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate, but the answers weren't helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often doing recently (because of lack integration with Android Studio) next in my test code:

```
System.out.println("TEST");
```

And run `gradle` with:

```
gradle testDebug -i
```

Comment: I use "gradlew test" to run my tests. What should I do to see any debug output... System.out or Log.d()?

Comment: First search with "Robolectric + Log" leads tohttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219915/where-is-log-output-written-to-when-using-robolectric-roboguice. Did you check it?

Comment: Yes, but the answers were not helpful for me. Maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: I see your comment. So with that solution just run gradle with `-i` flag

Comment: More details here http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html

Comment: The -i argument works for me, too. Unfortunately my whole app code is cluttered with Log.d() commands. I'm afraid I have to insert additional System.out.println() commands.

Answer (score 1):

Put this as a VM argument to your run configuration (in Android Studio):

```
-Drobolectric.logging=stdout
```